# Display cuts off launcher, everything's blurry, Hulu choppy, system slower than Vista

Tags: 12.10, performance, gpu

Just installed 12.10 64bit. Display cuts off launcher, every thing's blurry, Hulu choppy, overall the system is slower than Vista.

I'm guessing it's a GPU problem? I have a GeForce 9300M, but the 'System Details' shows 'Graphics: Unknown'. Where do I start?

Comment: Have you tried installing drivers for it? http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming 12.10 and not 12.*1*.
This release is still not stable, and the GPU problem in 12.10 have been bugging every other user since the release. Try popping into IRC channel #ubuntu, every other user is complaining about the same problem. I have an ATI Readon GPU that is causing the same problem with ATI drivers but reverting back to the X drivers I managed to reduce the problem down to a working environment. You can try to revert to X drivers by going to `System setting > Software sources > Additional Drivers` and select **X.org X Server**

I'd recommend you to stick to 12.04 if you are new to linux as that is pretty much stable and also a long term supported release.

Comment: Yup, I've seen a *lot* of people complaining about proprietary graphics with 12.10.  Best bet is to stick with 12.04.  The other issue you might be having is with mesa 9; I have had awful performance with it on my Arch box and I'm currently just keeping my system on 8.0.4.